# Vue.js equivalent method to window.addEventListener('load', function ()

Tags: vue.js

In a compoent  scripy I have the following function, can I set an equivalent function in created() or mounted () ??

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   mode = router.currentRoute.query.mode
   actionCode = router.currentRoute.query.oobCode
  // apiKey = router.currentRoute.query.apiKey
   continueUrl = router.currentRoute.query.continueUrl
   switch (mode) {
     case 'resetPassword':
       // handleResetPassword(actionCode, continueUrl)
       break
     case 'recoverEmail':
       // handleRecoverEmail(actionCode)
       break
     case 'verifyEmail':
       handleVerifyEmail(actionCode, continueUrl)
       break
     default:
       console.log('ERROR mode: ', mode)
       // Error: invalid mode.
   }
 })
```

and the set the handleVerifyEmail(actionCode, continueUrl) function as a method ??

thanks for feedback

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are trying to ask here but you do not need `window.addEventListener('load', () => {})` if you are using `mounted()`

Comment: Yes you can declare that code in a `mounted()` and yes you can declare that as a method. Why do you ask?

Comment: This is exactly my question ...  which hook ?  mounted() or before Mount() ...   thnaks for your feedback

Comment: In my opinion, it should be on the 'created' hook...

Comment: t hanks ... running fine now ..